# How to copy build artifacts from Azure DevOps to Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: python, selenium, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to copy build artifacts to Azure virtual Machine,

1. I have tried to create key pair in virtual machine and used that for service connection in azure devops for **copy file over ssh task** but getting errors i.e. Error: Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: privateKey value does not contain a (valid) private key.
2. We also tried with **Windows Machine File Copy task** but getting error i.e. network path not found, we have gone through this error & done configuration required for this but same error is coming.

What steps should I perform or check to solve these errors?
Is there any other way to copy artifacts on virtual machine from DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up self hosted agent in your Azure VM and then the build artifact will generate in the machine.

And if you are based on Microsoft agent, please notice whether the pipeline is in the allowed address of the Azure VM.

Also, there is a FTP task it can also been used to transfer files